# Best way to update an ActiveRecord attribute from a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a `Model` with an attribute `votes`. I have a link in a view that needs to increment the value of `votes` - what is the best way to do this?

I am currently trying a link like:

```
<%= link_to 'Up', '#', :method => :voteup %>
```

and a `voteup` method in the `model_controller` but this isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way would be this:

In `config/routes.rb`:

```
resources :quotes do
  member do
    post :upvote
  end
end
```

And your link:

```
<%= link_to 'Up', upvote_quote_path(@quote), :method => :post %>
```

Note that we use a POST request, which is more appropriate than a GET request when modifying a record.

Comment: That should probably be `<%= link_to 'Up', upvote_quote_path(@quote), :method => :post %>`, otherwise he will still get a "No route matches" error since it'll be trying to do a GET request.

Comment: Still get `No route matches {:controller=>"quotes", :action=>"upvote"}` :/

Answer (score 1):

:method is only supposed to be used to specify between POST, GET, DELETE, and PUT requests. Your second parameter of link_to should be the action you want to execute in your controller.

```
<%= link_to "Up", :action => :voteup %>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I get this when I try it: `No route matches {:controller=>"quotes", :action=>"voteup"}` And I used `:voteup` not `"voteup"` in my code as well